# Manipulate positioning of jQuery Mobile Footer

Tags: jquery, mobile, position, footer

I have a question that has been viewed, but with no answers or comments on the matter, so I thought I'd try to simplify my question. For those curious about my overall issue, please see the link: [Persistent header in jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258866/persistent-header-in-jquery-mobile)

Anyways, my question is how can I force the JQM footer to be at the top instead of the bottom? Here's the code for the JQM footer. It persists fine across page transitions, but it is at the foot of the page and I need it at the head:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="navBar" id="navigationBar">
    <img src="images/bgheader.png" />
</div>
```

I'm already looking into rebuilding it with Sencha, but since I have a deadline of tomorrow, I don't think that's possible. This persistent header is the only thing missing at the moment (JQM headers don't stay when the page transitions for some reason).

Comment: maybe im missing something here, but i just tested the following in firebug and it works fine... I add the following css as a style attribute to the header div "top:0px; position:fixed; z-index:999". Let me know if this is on the right track and ill post it as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar issue.

In my case I wanted the footer stay exactly in the bottom of the page so I wrapped the footer div into a new div positioned where I need to.

Let the code speak for itself:

```
<style> 
.footer-wrapper {

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

then

```
<div class='footer-wrapper'>
    <div data-role='footer' >
        footer content blah blah blah
    </div>
</div>
```

In this way you can move the footer wrapper freely (as every other normal div, not managed by jQuery Mobile's css) for example, in your case, you have to delete the `bottom: 0px;` attribute and change it in `top: -header's height-px;`

I hope it helps!

Comment: combine this with .ui-content {margin-bottom: 35px;} to support long pages.

Answer (score 2):

In the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-footers.html) it is stated:

> In situations where the footer is a
> global navigation element, you may
> want it to appear fixed in place
> between page transitions. This can be
> accomplished by using the persistent
> footer feature included in jQuery
> Mobile.
>
> To make a footer stay in place between
> transitions, add the data-id attribute
> to the footer of all relevant pages
> and use the same id value for each.
> For example, by adding
> data-id="myfooter" to the current page
> and the target page, the framework
> will keep the footer anchors in the
> same spot during the page animation.
>
> PLEASE NOTE: This effect will only
> work correctly if the header and
> footer toolbars are set to
> data-position="fixed" so they are in
> view during the transition.

So the same applies to the header. Instead of trying to move the footer, fix the header to be persistent.

I found an example [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/getting-started-with-jquery-mobile.html), under Making footers and headers persistent.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work because the header won't achieve this feature if I do as that example states: `stays in-place (never moves) between page transitions like the footer can be designed to do`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, at least not by using the JQM footer. The documentation doesn't reveal any attributes you can set which would change the position and JQM is actively managing the position on the `<div>` itself. It's modifying it directly as something like `style='top: -1304px'` and it changes values every time you scroll or change screens. So, you can't even change it by modifying the CSS. JQM will always win, since it's modifying the inline styles.

I think the main reason that you're stuck is that JQM is giving you an assumed page layout. Your common navigation controls are **supposed** to be at the bottom of the screen and the top of the screen should display something different on every page, with possibly a back button. That's how they envisioned it and, thus far, they haven't developed any other layout possibilities.

You may be able to accomplish your goal by taking an entirely different approach, but we'd need a clearer definition of your goal first.

Best of luck to you. Hopefully, your stakeholders like having the fixed elements at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following css to your page or to the bottom of the css file.

Please note I have not tested this code on mobile devices..

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .ui-header {
        position: fixed !important;
        top: 0 !important;
        z-index: 99;
    }
    .ui-content {
        margin-top: 35px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Please avoid on relying on !important with css, it's considered an anti-pattern

Comment: @Motocarota The answer is 5 years old,and is just an example, you can of course use specificity or other classes.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Inside each page div, include a div with data-role "footer", as below.

```
<div data-role="page" id="something">
   <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="navFooter" 
      role="contentinfo" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;">
      <div data-role="navbar" role="navigation">
          ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The inline style, in my app, prevented the navbar from being pushed down when content is added to the middle of the page, using something like this:

```
$('#contentDiv').append('<p>some html</p>');
```

It's unfortunate that the navbar must be repeated in each page div.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success with this, inside of each data-role="page":

```
<div data-role="footer" data-id="page_header" class="fixed_header">
 <h1>My Page</h1>
</div>
```

css:

```
.fixed_header {
    position:fixed !important;
    top:0px !important;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
```

And I've actually been able to have a second "real" footer, as well, fixed to the bottom of the page. I've tested this on my HTC Amaze, and the iOS simulator.

I would be interested to know if this is working on other devices.

Comment: Please avoid on relying on !important with css, it's considered an anti-pattern