# jQuery mobile page height

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, css

For the past day I have been trying to figure out how to change the min-height styling on a jQuery mobile page when viewing in mobile safari. I have tried, inline styles, overriding ui-page styles and have yet to find a way to override the height of data-role="page". Ideally if the page "content" is less than the "page" height I would like the "page" height to automatically adjust to the "content". I have attached an illustration to better explain the issue.

[image: jQuery Webpage Diagram]

```
<div data-role="page">
     <div data-role="header">
             Header Elements
     </div>
     <div data-role="content" class="homeNav">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-filter="false">
                <li><a href="expertise.html">Expertise</a></li>
                <li><a href="greatesthits.html">Greatest Hits</a></li>
                <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="mindset.html">Mindset</a></li>
                <li><a href="connect.html">Connect</a></li>
             </ul>  
     </div><!-- /content -->

     <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
             Footer elements
     </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: I know this is old, but please see this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6694170/480303).  Unless I misunderstand what the OP is looking for, he does not need to manipulate the page height.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `min-height` of the `data-role="page"` element is set via JavaScript in a `resize` event handler for the `window` object. You can create your own JavaScript that resizes the page differently:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).bind('resize', function (event) {
        var content_height = $.mobile.activePage.children('[data-role="content"]').height(),
            header_height  = $.mobile.activePage.children('[data-role="header"]').height(),
            footer_height  = $.mobile.activePage.children('[data-role="footer"]').height(),
            window_height  = $(this).height();

        if (content_height < (window_height - header_height - footer_height)) {
            $.mobile.activePage.css('min-height', (content_height + header_height + footer_height));
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.mobile.activePage.children('[data-role="footer"]').css('top', 0);
            }, 500);
        }
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sAs5z/1/

Notice the `setTimeout` used to set the `fixed-position-footer`; the timeout duration can probably be made smaller. This is used because the jQuery Mobile Framework was re-positioning the `fixed-position-footer` back to the bottom of the page. An example of this can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/sAs5z/

Another note, you may want to only re-position the `fixed-position-footer` element and leave the page's `min-height` property the same; this will make the page gradient cover the whole screen but the footer won't have any space between it and the content. Here is a demo of this method: http://jsfiddle.net/sAs5z/2/

Comment: Please checkout the link below on a mobile device to see the problem that I am having with the device height.
 
http://go2mktg.com/weblast/go25037/mobile/expertise.html#planning

I have tried implementing the code above but am still getting extra space below my content unless adding a minimum height on my content div which forces scrolling. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I cannot find a way to override the styling on the page background. I want to make it black but it seems to always default to light grey.

Comment: If all you want to do is make the page black, adjust the CSS for the `data-role="page"` elements: `.ui-page { background : #000; }`. If it isn't sticking it's because it's being overwritten and you can add `!important` like this: `.ui-page { background : #000 !important; }`.

Comment: I tried adding the background style with !important still with no luck, see here: http://go2mktg.com/weblast/go25037/mobile/css/m_style.css 
Ideally I would like to eliminate scrolling if the content is shorter than the device height and fill the extra space with black.

Comment: You didn't add `background : #000`, you added `background-color : #000` which will not overwrite the gradient that you want to get rid of. I believe that gradients are considered to be images so you need to use: `background : #000`

Comment: That will do, thanks alot for your help! Out of curiosity, have you found an easy way to resize/auto-fit content when rotating the orientation to landscape? Ideally I would like to lock certain pages in a portrait orientation but from everything I have read this is not possible in mobile safari and only in the iOS development environment.

Comment: It's easily done for a native iOS application, you can set the supported orientations right in Xcode. For web-apps you can use a CSS transform to rotate the `body` element on orientation change to mimic forcing portrait view.

Comment: @negrelja Here is a simple example of forcing portrait orientation on a web-app: http://jsfiddle.net/MJ5Ar/8/. It's not perfect but it will get you started.

Comment: I tried implementing and tweaking the attached jsfiddle script but unfortunately the content goes haywire in landscape mode and is resizing to much larger than the screen area. Once you rotate back to portrait the layout is shifting and resizing all out of whack. Is there anyway for landscape to auto fit the content better? Seems to always size about 3 times the size of the screen. I thought I read that this is a bug in jQuery mobile. Thanks again for your time on this!

Comment: You need to set the dimensions of the `.ui-page` (`data-role="page") elements on orientation change. Here is an update but it still isn't behaving properly: http://jsfiddle.net/MJ5Ar/10/

Answer (score 4):

Old ticket but I have a solution which I prefer more. It specifically unbinds the resize event through some jQuery internals hacking. I don't like Jasper's solution because it depends on one event firing to block another, and events in theory should never know about each other / you should never depend on the order in which events fire.

```
$(function() {
    // WARNING: Extremely hacky code ahead. jQuery mobile automatically
    // sets the current "page" height on page resize. We need to unbind the
    // resize function ONLY and reset all pages back to auto min-height.
    // This is specific to jquery 1.8

    // First reset all pages to normal
    $('[data-role="page"]').css('min-height', 'auto');

    // Is this the function we want to unbind?
    var check = function(func) {
        var f = func.toLocaleString ? func.toLocaleString() : func.toString();
        // func.name will catch unminified jquery mobile. otherwise see if
        // the function body contains two very suspect strings
        if(func.name === 'resetActivePageHeight' || (f.indexOf('padding-top') > -1 && f.indexOf('min-height'))) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // First try to unbind the document pageshow event
    try {
        // This is a hack in jquery 1.8 to get events bound to a specific node
        var dHandlers = $._data(document).events.pageshow;

        for(x = 0; x < dHandlers.length; x++) {
            if(check(dHandlers[x].handler)) {
                $(document).unbind('pageshow', dHandlers[x]);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch(e) {}

    // Then try to unbind the window handler
    try {
        var wHandlers = $._data(window).events.throttledresize;

        for(x = 0; x < wHandlers.length; x++) {
            if(check(wHandlers[x].handler)) {
                $(window).unbind('throttledresize', wHandlers[x]);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch(e) {}
});
```

Comment: I guess this `$.mobile.resetActivePageHeight();` does it all, when called manually. I've faced a problem when appending a fixed header dynamically, the page's height wasn't updating after calling enhancement. Calling that function fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue when showing a popup with an overlay $.mobile.resetActivePageHeight(); did the trick for me. Thanx!

Comment: I haven't used jQM in a while but the new documentation weems to state that this is the way to re-adjust your page height when dynamically adding toolbars. Also, now looking at my solution up top I think this could be done with just CSS.