# Content auto height adjust depends on page height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I've encountered issue, where i need height of my content to be specific in pixels(for google map to show correctly). However i dont know on which devices my site will be used(cellphones, smartphones) and what screen resolution will be. I have an idea how to implement this, but since i'm using jquery mobile i'm not sure how to do that. The idea is pretty simple: get height of page and then `content.height = page.height-(footer.height+header.height)`

Here is my html code:

```
<html>
<body style="margin:0">
    <div data-role="page" class="page-nearme">
        <div data-role="header" data-id="navbar" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false"></div>
        <!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="search-panel">
                <input id="target" type="search" placeholder="Search Box">
            </div>
            <div id="map_canvas" style=""></div>
            </div>
            <!-- tabbar -->
            <div data-role="footer" data-id="main_footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true" data-visible-on-page-show="false" id="fxedfooter" data-tap-toggle="false" onclick="showfooter">
                <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a id="menu-item-home" data-icon="custom" href="index.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
                        <li><a id="menu-item-near-me" data-icon="custom" href="near-me.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">&nbsp;</a></li>
                        <li><a id="menu-item-rewards" data-icon="custom" href="rewards.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
                        <li><a id="menu-item-invite" data-icon="custom" href="invite.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
                        <li><a id="menu-item-profile" data-icon="custom" href="profile.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /navbar -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

PS i tried solution in [jQuery mobile page height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929786/jquery-mobile-page-height?rq=1) that didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like this:

```
$('div[data-role="content"]').height(window.innerHeight - ($('div[data-role="header"]').height() + $('div[data-role="footer"]').height()));
```

Comment: this actually worked, but how do i use not innerHeight, but whole body/html height?

Comment: `window.innerHeight()` return the height (in pixels) of the browser window viewport. So I assume that's what you're looking for. Also, see the documentation of `innerHeight()` and the difference to `outerHeight()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.innerHeight